# Relationship between the generating elements given by the Hamiltonian cycle of a Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, cayley-graphs, hamiltonicity

[image]

Consider the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$ generated by the generating set $S=\{g_1=(1,0), g_2=(0,1)\}$. Then $|g_1|=3, |g_2|=5$.

Consider a Hamiltonian cycle, $ABCDEFGHIKJLMNO$. Then the Hamiltonian cycle can be expressed in terms of the generating elements as follows.

$g_1^2 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2 g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2 g_1^2 g_2^{-4} = e$

Since the group is abelian, we can simplify it to be as follows, right?

$g_1^3 g_2^0 = e$

Then can we adjust the $e$ on the right hand side in terms of the generating elements as,
$g_1^3 g_2^0 = g_1^0 g_2^0$ or as $g_1^3 g_2^0 = g_1^3 g_2^5$ (because the orders of the elements are 3 and 5 respectively)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks @joriki

Comment: When we simplify a product expression of any Hamiltonian cycle we obtain $e$ but such reduction “forgets” information about structure of the cycle.